# Best (fastest and memory saving) Java collection / data structure to concurrently insert and delete items

Tags: java, performance, memory, collections, concurrency

I intend to write a Spring Boot application in Java 8 which shall allow to insert (float) values over a large number of TCP connections. These values shall be kept for a defined time period and deleted afterwards. It may be that more than 250,000 values can be inserted (concurrently) in a short time period.

I am looking for the best Java collection to store float values in terms of:

- fast insertion coming in over a lot of TCP connections
- fast deletion after a defined time (maybe using Timer class?)

I don't need sortation or so, I only have to sum up the values of the values in the collection (frequently requested) and delete all the values older than x minutes / hours / days / ... (whatever). I think about deleting the items/elements using Timer/TimerTask!?!

Because I have to compare the timestamp of inputting the value into the collection I think I cannot only store the (float) value but also a Timestamp (Instant?) value, hence, I have to use a Bean (Pojo) maybe with attributes

```
private float value;
private Instant time; (Instant.now();)
```

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for a database? Maybe a time-series one.

Comment: You can use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. You add new elements to the tail of the queue. At some point (adding new items, making calculations or periodically) you remove old expired elements from the head of the queue. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Comment: I forget to mention: a DB is not intended to use (at least in this stage).

Comment: Is the deletion time known at the insertion time?

Comment: Also is the deletion period the same for all elements?

Comment: Items are inserted into the collection and all items older than 60 seconds shall be removed. From all remaining intems (younger than 60 seconds) I want to calculate the average (sum of sale amounts / number of itmes).

Comment: Be aware that getting an _accurate_ sum of a quarter of a million different `float` values is not as simple as it might first seem:  http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~alexss/2015/10/16/improving-accuracy-summation.html

Comment: It sounds like you can use `DoubleAdder` for the values and an `AtomicInteger` for the count. Then double that, flip between instances every time period, and store the summary into an `ArrayDeque`. To drop off old summaries in a circular fashion, just poll after adding when over the size threshold.